# reading from "/dev/random" in c

Tags: c, random

i am reading high quality 16 bit random numbers of type uint16_t from /dev/random 
and i am getting numbers as big as: 2936814755. Are these correct

```
int myFile = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);            
unsigned int rand;            
uint16_t randomNum = read(myFile, &rand, sizeof(rand)) ;
printf(" %u ", rand);
close(myFile);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

unsigned int probably isn't 16 bit on your pc architecture. If you want to be sure use uint16_t instead.

```
uint16_t rand;            
int ret = read(myFile, &rand, sizeof(rand)) ;
```

I think you were confusing the return value of read (ret that should be int and is the numbers of bytes read) and the generated random number (rand that should be uint16_t and is the random number generated).

Comment: He's printing rand instead of printing randomNum. Does it really matter that he's using rand in the read?

Comment: I don't understand your objection.

Comment: randomNum is uint16_t - I don't remember exact rules for C. Won't assigning to a lower precision discard the extra bits, and result in a 16 bit rand? Or does it get promoted? It looks like he's printing the wrong variable.

Comment: he was using randomNum to store the return value. So randomNum variable isn't random at all :). No. He's printing the right variable rand(if he want to print the random number generated).

Comment: Right! My brain is too far out of practice. Yay for returning status codes, and taking a location to store the read result as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Change 'unsigned int rand' to 'unsigned short rand' in your code and you will be fine !